How to use `pycountry.db.Country` objects as a `pd.DataFrame` index?
I am creating a dataset collecting data for a given set of countries. To avoid any ambiguity, I would like to use a pycountry.db.Country object to represent each country.
However, when setting the country as the index of my pd.DataFrame, I can't select (.loc[]) a record by passing a country, I'm getting this type of error — despite the record existing:

raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

How to select a record in my pd.DataFrame, given a pycountry.db.Country object?
Here is a working example:
import pandas as pd
import pycountry

aruba: pycountry.db.Country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3="ABW")
belgium: pycountry.db.Country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3="BEL")
canada: pycountry.db.Country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3="CAN")

data: list[dict] = [
    {"country": aruba, "population": 106_203},
    {"country": belgium, "population": 11_429_336},
    {"country": canada, "population": 37_058_856},
]

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("country", inplace=True)
# df.index = df.index.astype(dtype="category")  # optional: doesn't change the outcome

assert df.index[1] == belgium
assert df.index[1] is belgium

belgium_data = df.loc[belgium]  # <-- fails with "None of [Index([('alpha_2', 'BE'),\n('alpha_3', 'BEL'),\n('flag', ''),\n('name', 'Belgium'),\n('numeric', '056'),\n('official_name', 'Kingdom of Belgium')],\ndtype='object', name='country')] are in the [index]"


Explanation
Pandas treats your object as a list-like object, which is why you cannot use it as a key for loc, since it will try to iterate over the objects in the list.
>>> from pandas.core.dtypes.common import is_list_like, is_scalar
>>> is_scalar(belgium)
False
>>> is_list_like(belgium)
True

See What datatype is considered 'list-like' in Python? for more about is_list_like
Workaround
Interestingly, this works:
>>> df.loc[[belgium]].iloc[0]
population    11429336
Name: Country(alpha_2='BE', alpha_3='BEL', flag='', name='Belgium', numeric='056', official_name='Kingdom of Belgium'), dtype: int64

so if you really really want to use the object as an index, you can work around it with this.
Or, getting even more ridiculous, making the object not iterable:
>>> belgium.__iter__ = None
>>> df.loc[belgium]
population    11429336
Name: Country(__iter__=None, alpha_2='BE', alpha_3='BEL', flag='', name='Belgium', numeric='056', official_name='Kingdom of Belgium'), dtype: int64

But I'm sure this would break some other functionality on your code, since __iter__  seems to be implemented on Country to make it possible to cast it to dict easily.
Recommendation
Objects as an index is not maybe the best of practices if your dataset is large. What I would recommend would be to use for example alpha_3 as the index instead, and keep the object in a separate column. You would still avoid ambiguity, but would not get in trouble with overly complex index types.
data: list[dict] = [
    {"index": aruba.alpha_3, "country": aruba, "population": 106_203},
    {"index": belgium.alpha_3, "country": belgium, "population": 11_429_336},
    {"index": canada.alpha_3, "country": canada, "population": 37_058_856},
]

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("index", inplace=True)

assert df.loc[belgium.alpha_3]["country"] == belgium


Thank you! I haven't given up on the object approach (see my answer), but your explanation is exactly what I was looking for.

While I agree with the recommendation of @Teemu Risikko not to use objects as an index, his excellent answer also made me realize why your code does work in versions of pycountry <= 23.12.7.
In 23.12.7, your objects would be pycountry.db.Data, there still without the __iter__ method (see 23.12.7 db.py L8).
Since 23.12.11, the objects are pycountry.db.Country, inheriting from Data with __iter__ (see 23.12.11 db.py L32, L38).
E.g., if you want to insist:

downgrade to 23.12.7 (using pip install pycountry==23.12.7 or equivalent), and;
update the type hints (pycountry.db.Country -> pycountry.db.Data)

import pandas as pd
import pycountry

belgium: pycountry.db.Data = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3="BEL")

data: list[dict] = [
    {"country": belgium, "population": 11_429_336}
]

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("country", inplace=True)

df.loc[belgium]

Output:

population    11429336
Name: Country(alpha_2='BE', alpha_3='BEL', flag='', name='Belgium', numeric='056', official_name='Kingdom of Belgium'), dtype: int64

print(pycountry.__version__)
# 23.12.7


Thank you! Understanding why was a pycountry.db.Country object not usable as a selector helped me craft an approach which is "just right" for my needs (see my answer).

Thanks to Teemu Risikko's answer, as well as ouroboros1's one, I have generated a simply Country(StrEnum) class which allows me to combine:

validation (only valid pycountry countries can be instantiated),
combining a country's trigram (easy) and name (useful for display),
selecting from a Country object (any string isn't valid).

The valid instances of the Enum are computed automatically.
import pandas as pd
import pycountry
from enum import StrEnum

Country = StrEnum(
    value="Country",
    names={country.alpha_3: country.name for country in pycountry.countries},
    module=__name__,
)

aruba = Country.ABW  # <-- One can select a country by its alpha-3 code
belgium = Country.BEL
canada = Country("Canada")  # <-- One can select a country by (standardized) name too

data: list[dict] = [
    {"country": aruba, "population": 106_203},
    {"country": belgium, "population": 11_429_336},
    {"country": canada, "population": 37_058_856},
]

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("country", inplace=True)

assert df.index[1] == belgium
assert df.index[1] is belgium

belgium_data = df.loc[belgium]


The downside is that mypy raise attr-defined errors as it cannot process the list of members dynamically (cf. https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4865#issuecomment-592560696), so you may want to use Country["USA"] instead of the, IMO more elegant, Country.USA.
